# Routes are getting shutdown automatically in servicemix/fuse

Tags: java, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

It keeps on getting started and shutsdown in few seconds and is keep on looping.
Below is the log of start and shutdown of routes continuously

```
2016-01-04 14:35:03,340 | INFO  | Thread-207       | BlueprintCamelContext            | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Apache Camel 2.14.1 (CamelContext: NIP_Interfaces_Context) is shutting down
2016-01-04 14:35:03,340 | INFO  | Thread-207       | BlueprintCamelContext            | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Apache Camel 2.14.1 (CamelContext: NIP_Interfaces_Context) uptime not started
2016-01-04 14:35:03,340 | INFO  | Thread-207       | BlueprintCamelContext            | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Apache Camel 2.14.1 (CamelContext: NIP_Interfaces_Context) is shutdown in 0.000 seconds
2016-01-04 14:35:03,527 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | ClientRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.ClientRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,527 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | ClientRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.ClientRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,527 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder   | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder   | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | DocumentRouteBuilder             | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.DocumentRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | DocumentRouteBuilder             | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.DocumentRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | PolicyRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PolicyRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | PolicyRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PolicyRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | PricingRouteBuilder              | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PricingRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | PricingRouteBuilder              | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PricingRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | QuotConversionRouteBuilder       | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotConversionRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | QuotConversionRouteBuilder       | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotConversionRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | QuotCreationRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotCreationRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | QuotCreationRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotCreationRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:03,543 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder     | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.ncp.routes.UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:04,673 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder     | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.ncp.routes.UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:04,673 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder    | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:05,340 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder    | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:05,340 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:06,471 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:06,471 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | TcDetailsRouteBuilder            | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TcDetailsRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:06,974 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | TcDetailsRouteBuilder            | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TcDetailsRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:06,974 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | CustomerSearchRouteBuilder       | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.ws.routes.CustomerSearchRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,483 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | CustomerSearchRouteBuilder       | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.ws.routes.CustomerSearchRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,498 | INFO  | rint Extender: 3 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.2 | Bundle com.ndfs.nip.interfaces.nip-interfaces is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=http)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver)), (&(component=https)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]
2016-01-04 14:35:07,498 | INFO  | Thread-209       | BlueprintCamelContext            | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Apache Camel 2.14.1 (CamelContext: NIP_Interfaces_Context) is shutting down
2016-01-04 14:35:07,498 | INFO  | Thread-209       | BlueprintCamelContext            | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Apache Camel 2.14.1 (CamelContext: NIP_Interfaces_Context) uptime not started
2016-01-04 14:35:07,498 | INFO  | Thread-209       | BlueprintCamelContext            | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Apache Camel 2.14.1 (CamelContext: NIP_Interfaces_Context) is shutdown in 0.000 seconds
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | ClientRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.ClientRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | ClientRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.ClientRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder   | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder   | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.CoverageDefaultingRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | DocumentRouteBuilder             | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.DocumentRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | DocumentRouteBuilder             | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.DocumentRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | PolicyRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PolicyRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | PolicyRouteBuilder               | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PolicyRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | PricingRouteBuilder              | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PricingRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | PricingRouteBuilder              | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.PricingRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | QuotConversionRouteBuilder       | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotConversionRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | QuotConversionRouteBuilder       | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotConversionRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | QuotCreationRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotCreationRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | QuotCreationRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.as400.routes.QuotCreationRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:07,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder     | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.ncp.routes.UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:08,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder     | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.ncp.routes.UpdateAuthStatusRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:08,592 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder    | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:09,108 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder    | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.NIPtoSBMTcDetailsRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:09,108 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:10,162 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder         | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TaxIdDetailsRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:10,162 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | TcDetailsRouteBuilder            | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TcDetailsRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:10,708 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | TcDetailsRouteBuilder            | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Route (class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.sbm.routes.TcDetailsRouteBuilder) started successfully in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
2016-01-04 14:35:10,708 | INFO  | rint Extender: 2 | CustomerSearchRouteBuilder       | 8 - com.ndfs.nip.framework.nip-framework - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Starting the route class com.ndfs.nip.hdi.ws.routes.CustomerSearchRouteBuilder in container NIP_Interfaces_Context
```

Also the blueprint extender: 1, blueprint extender: 2 keeps on coming. Checked the log level in debug mode, there are no unusual errors. Can someone help me deal with such issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

`BlueprintContainerImpl           | 19 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.2 | Bundle com.ndfs.nip.interfaces.nip-interfaces is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=http)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver)), (&(component=https)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]`

indicates that you need to install `camel-http` component that has the http component. In the JBoss Fuse shell type: `features:install camel-http` to install it.